# Delete multiple records with composite key in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a composite primary key.

**ReportsTable**:
`id1,id2,data,...`

I want to delete multiple rows based on the composite key list.
Eg. `[(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]`

How to delete the records which match the ids list using sqlalchemy? I tried to do it by constructing the query by chaining `or_`s in a loop.

```
tuple_list = [(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
with runtime.terminating_sn('adb', 'user', cid) as session:
    base_or = or_(
        and_(Reports.id1 == tuple_list[0][0], Reports.id2 == tuple_list[0][1]),
        and_(Reports.id1 == tuple_list[1][0], Reports.id2 == tuple_list[1][1]))
    for i in range(2, len(tuple_list)):
        base_or = or_(base_or, and_(Reports.id1 == tuple_list[i+1][0],
                                    Reports.id2 == tuple_list[i+1][1]))
    session.query(Reports).filter(base_or).delete()
    session.commit()
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it in python.